# how can I determine a directive's parent's html tag?

Tags: angular

say I have a template containing:

```
<tr>
  <th><ng-template someDirective></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><ng-template someDirective></td>
<tr>
```

and then the component has:

```
@ViewChildren(SomeDirective) list!:QueryList<SomeDirective>;
```

When I iterate over the list, how can I tell which is within a `<th>` and which is within a `<td>` (other than by index knowing what is in the template)?

I see that I can do:

```
this.list.toArray()[n].viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.parentElement.tagName === 'TH'
```

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**
I would also be ok with doing:

```
<tr>
  <th><ng-template class="header" someDirective></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><ng-template class="data" someDirective></td>
<tr>
```

If there is an easy way to evaluate the class for the `SomeDirective` element?

`element.nativeElement.classList` is undefined in this context...  How would I be able to access the class on an `ng-template` ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular's  element defines a template that is not rendered by default. So you can't access to classList in this case. Use `div` tag instead of     `ng-template` and iterate the list inside `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook. Otherwise this don't work.